# Андроид-студия со временем отключает потоковое видео и звук в системе

Tags: windows, android-studio

Через некоторое время работы со студией и особенно эмулятором, перестает работать потоковое видео типа youtube, а также проигрывающие любой звук плейеры (iTunes и пр). И то, и то стоит как будто на паузе.
Перезагрузка компа временно решает проблему.
Что в андроид-студии блокирует подобные вещи? Как этого избежать?
Система - win7 64, студия 1.4

UPD Как один из вариантов решения, нашел такое - отключить и включить звуковой драйвер в настройках виндос.

Comment: Попробуйте посмотреть на системные параметры - CPU, RAM и тому подобное

Comment: дождался еще одного такого случая. студия была открыта весь день (без эмулятора). CPU занят на 5%, память на 55% (из чего студия конечно берет большую часть). 
Что конкретно стоит посмотреть?

Comment: так и завис этот вопрос а проблема тем временем не исчезла
добавил 8 гигов памяти, не помогло